# A percentagem dentro de uma frase deve ser por extenso ou com o símbolo de %?

Tags: português-europeu, números, frases

A percentagem dentro de uma frase deve se por externo ou com o símbolo de %
Exemplo:
"Recebi 20 por cento a mais relativamente ao mês transacto" ou 
"Recebi 20 % a mais relativamente ao mês transacto"

Comment: FALSO, não ligar muito: Pequeno aparte: entre números e unidades (ou ordens de grandeza, ou percentagens), não deve haver um espaço; e de maneira igual entre um número e o símbolo de percentagem: 30kg, 18s, 3dB, 20%.

Comment: @ANeves Nas convenções do SI (usadas em practicamente toda a literatura científica), o espaço entre o número e as unidades é obrigatório. Geralmente usa-se um espaço rígido (non-breaking space).

Comment: O quê?!? o_o Estou parvo prá vida... então andei este tempo todo errado, e ninguém se dignou corrigir-me até tu apareceres?

Comment: [Segundo a Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_System_of_Units#General_rules): «The value of a quantity is written as a number **followed by a space** (representing a multiplication sign) and a unit symbol; e.g., 2.21 kg, 7.3×102 m2, 22 K. **This rule explicitly includes the percent sign** (%)[2] and the symbol for degrees Celsius (°C).[2] Exceptions are the symbols for plane angular degrees, minutes, and seconds (°, ′, and ″), which are placed immediately after the number with no intervening space.»

Comment: O correto seria utilizar o ponto acima como resposta. Concordam? O utilizador pode responder às suas próprias perguntas, para estes casos?

Comment: CIMend, o utilizador pode **sempre** responder às suas próprias perguntas. :) Em qualquer caso, sem restrições.

Comment: Acho que os comentários não respondem à pergunta. Os comentários dizem que ao escrever percentagem por símbolo se deve usar um espaço entre os números e o símbolo; mas a pergunta é sobre se se deve escrever por extenso ou com o símbolo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como indicou o @ANeves em comentário, a razão para juntar o número e as unidades, sem espaço a separar, é para evitar que os processadores de texto por acaso ao mudarem de linha separem as duas partes. (Não ficava bem, uma linha terminar com o número e a próxima começar com a unidade.)

De resto, escrever por extenso ou com o símbolo depende do contexto. Escrever "por cento" pode ser usado num livro, no jornalismo, num email (sob a premissa que não tenha de ser repetido muitas vezes). Mas raramente em documentos técnicos nas secções que tratam dos números, pode no entanto ser usado a meio da prosa se queremos referir a unidade.

Podemos acrescentar que há unidades mais complicadas, como o "Retorno sobre investimento" abreviado "ROI", que habitualmente são escritas por extenso a primeira vez e imediatamente seguidas da sigla entre parêntesis - após essa definição inicial só é usada a sigla.

No exemplo dado na pergunta, o tratamento dos números é pontual e a meio da prosa - nesse caso a opção mais elegante é escrever por extenso.

Comment: Não só se usa espaço entre o número e as unidades, como este é geralmente obrigatório (e em particular sobre o %, [5.3.7 da brochura do SI](https://www.bipm.org/en/publications/si-brochure/section5-3.html) diz "When it is used, a space separates the number and the symbol %"). Para evitar quebras de espaço basta usar um espaço rígido (Ctrl+Shift+Espaço no word ou ~ em latex, por exemplo).

Comment: Sim é verdade, não tive paciência para consultar um guia de estilo. O &nbsp e similares frequentmente são uma opção demasiado complicada para quem escreve um email, SMS, ou mensagem num chat. Quem escrever em LaTex e afins terá abundantes guias de estilo para orientar.

Comment: Eu não indiquei isso.

Comment: Pelo o exposto, o mais correta seria Actualizar a resposta ou inserir uma resposta nova. Concordam?

Comment: @ClMend ao fim do dia tento corrigir.

Comment: 100 % e não 100% ? Certo?!

Comment: @ClMend obrigado por me lembrares. Se alguma escrevo por estes dias, é por obrigação ou impulso. O que eu disse, na resposta, era a pensar nas formas correntes de comunicação emails, chats...Sim, nesses meios é recomendável, e usual, juntares o simbolo e o número. Se for num documento de outra natureza -publicação oficial- deves separar. É conforme o caso...